# "... и сестра их Лыбедь"

Tags: славянизмы, этимология, устаревшие-слова, топонимика

Смотрел недавно фильм "Сказка о царе Салтане". Там есть царевна Лебедь. И вспомнилась мне легенда об основателях города Киева. Ими являются, согласно легенде, братья Кий, Щек, Хорив и сестра их Лыбедь.

Я задумался -- странноватое имя -- **Лыбедь** !

Возможно я чего-то не знаю, и здесь на форуме мне подскажут, но если это имя происходит (как сразу кажется) от слова **"лебедь"**, то откуда там, в этом имени буква "Ы" ?

В Киеве есть небольшая речка Лыбедь. И в Рязани есть другая небольшая речка, тоже Лыбедь. Это что, какой-то старинный вариант произношения, через "ы" ?

По-украински обычно говорят "лебiдь" [лЭбидь] (на птицу лебедь, не на речку).

Итак, связано ли имя/название *Лыбедь* с названием птицы *лебедь* ? Если да, то почему оно пишется через "ы", а не через "е" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> По-украински обычно говорят "лебiдь" [лЭбидь] (на птицу лебедь, не на речку).

Вот и ответ. В древнерусском Э не могло следовать после твердого согласного. Несмотря на наличие даже специальных знаков для "смягчающего Э" ("йотованный есть"), которыми, впрочем, никто не пользовался, фактически все равно происходило смягчение во всех случаях. Лыбедь - наиболее близкий фонетически возможный вариант к "Лэбидь". Кстати, украинское Ы (И) заметно отличается от русского и произносится в разных позициях как нечто среднее между Э и Ы или даже как дифтонг эЫ (восходящий) или Ыэ (нисходящий).

Comment: >В древнерусском Э не могло следовать после твердого согласного. 

Спасибо за ответ. 

А "Ы" тоже не могло? Это же вроде из древней летописи взято? (я точно не помню откуда). 

Т.е. вы думаете, что это всё-таки украинское влияние. Возможно.

Comment: Почему Ы не могло? Оно-то как-раз и было возможным - и заменяло в некоторых случаях фонетических неприемлемое сочетание.

Comment: >Кстати, украинское Ы (И) заметно отличается от русского

Некоторые жители Украины этот звук Ы произносят очень мягко, почти как русское И. Но это к обсуждаемой теме не относится.

Comment: **tmp**, Ваш ответ хорош. И меня останавливает только одно, чтобы принять этот ответ. Основание Киева -- дело очень уж давнее. Как думаете, тогда уже существовали заметно отличающиеся славянские говоры? Я об этом слове *лебедь/лэбидь/лыбидь*.

Comment: Говоры-то существовали, общеславянская языковая общность начала распадаться на З-слаявянскую и Ю-В-славянскую не позднее IV-V века.
Только этот вопрос не имеет прямого отношения к теме. Фонетика разошлась позже. Просто ныне существующие языки по-разному передают некогда фонетически единое имя. Вас же не удивляет, что само название Киев по-украински звучит иначе, чем по-русски ("Кыйив"), хотя уж в этой-то части языки разошлись лет через тысячу после основания города. 
Так и с Лебедью. Каждый язык по-своему "стилизует" древний вариант имени, при том, что у каждого есть и современный.

Comment: Спасибо, ответ понятен. Жму кнопку и принимаю его :-). 

>Вас же не удивляет, что само название Киев по-украински звучит иначе, чем по-русски ("Кыйив"), хотя уж в этой-то части языки разошлись лет через тысячу после основания города.

Вообще меня с самого начала смутило (и остаётся непонятным сейчас), что в **российском** городе Рязань тоже есть речка Лыбедь... От российско-украинских границ он сравнительно далеко. Был бы близко -- тогда понятно -- там разговор мешаный и с российской, и с украинской стороны. Какие-то жители древн. Руси название перенесли, переселяясь с Приднепровья на восток?

Answer (score 0):

Ну хорошо Э не могла,говор был мягче,а редуцированная-Ъ могла?Откуда это слово?-из летописи.Кто писал летопись?-человек.Мог ли он взять за основу более древний источник?-мог.Мог ли он ошибится в трактовке одной буквы?-мог,приняв её за звук-Ы.

Comment: Мог ли переписчик ошибиться? Конечно мог. Могли ли 3 независящих друг от друга переписчика сделать одну и туже ошибку в одном и том же слове? Крайне маловероятно. Во всех известных списках ПВЛ, сестру звали именно Лыбѣдь.

Даже если предположить, что был звук "Ъ", а не "Ы", то это ничего не объясняет, а только запутывает. Звук этот безударный, и ударение в этом случае должно падать на ять. Слово получится, что-то вроде [лаб'Ад'а] Вопрос: по какой причине сместилось ударение на начало слова?

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть такой вопрос: имя Лебедь/Лыбедь насколько оно женское, если я не ошибаюсь есть и другой вариант более женственный - Лебёда? Есть ли какие-то материалы подтверждающие что в те времена Лыбедь было женским именем, кроме этой легенды? Также интересуют материалы о том, существовало ли в тоже время имя Лебёда?

Comment: Вопросы не здесь задают. Будьте внимательны!