# Кий, Щек, Хорив и сестра их Лыбидь

Tags: имена-собственные

Думаю, все знают легендарных основателей Киева. Но вот меня заинтересовали их имена - какие-то они не славянские, вроде. По крайней мере, ни одно из них не понятно. Да и имя сестры - где-то я читал, что раньше женских имен как таковых не было, а были либо отчества, либо прозвища. Хотя тут еще более-менее понятно значение (видимо, вариант слова "лебедь").
Или же все они не были славянами, как всем известные Рюрик с братьями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да нет, как раз по легенде-то вполне себе славяне.

А вот на самом деле... Тут что-то трудно утверждать, поскольку достоверность всей этой истории (а значит и существование подобных имен) весьма и весьма сомнительна.

**Кий**, как ни странно, именно кий - длинная палка, посох. Слово праславянское, дошедшее до современности благодаря бильярдистам. Скорее всего именно это слово и дало начало названию самого города (сравните со Стокгольм - остров палок). Возможно где-то там была рощица, пущенная на посохи. Хотя, в принципе, не как имя, но как прозвище вполне могло быть у высокого и худого человека.

**Щек** - полагают, что родственно "Чех", хотя тут тоже можно спорить, что первично, само имя или название горы Щекавица (Щековица), на которой этот Щек якобы жил. Если все-таки второе, то название горы легко объясняется её формой (есть что-то от обрюзгших, расплывшихся щек). Тут интересна этимология самого слова щека - видимо не только праславянского, но и вообще индоевропейского...

С **Хоривом** сложнее, скорее всего, как  Щек, -  по топониму, ныне исчезнувшему, горе Хорвица (Хоривица).

Насчет **Лыбеди** смотрите тут:
["... и сестра их Лыбедь"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/14583)

А вообще все это есть в Вики, хотя кое с чем я бы поспорил, уж больно много "всяких разных" версий, некритично включенных "до кучи".

//------

Происхождение имен и названий легенды

Имя Кий возводилось ко многим языкам. Наиболее авторитетными являются объяснения этого имени от славянского слова, означающего «палица, дубина, боевой молот», и от тюркского «высокий берег».

Имя Щек сопоставляется с именем Чеха, легендарного предка чехов. Название горы Щековица, на которой якобы жил Щек, сохранилось позже в форме Скавица.

Имя Хорив связано с названием горы Хоривица, которое не сохранилось в позднее время. Название горы сравнивают с иранским словом Haraiva — название горной страны. Народно-этимологически названием связывали с библейской горой Хорив[1].

Лыбедь — это небольшая речка, впадающая в Днепр. Имя Лыбедь возводят обычно к словам лебедь, луб, лыва. Другое название Киева, упомянутое Константином Багрянородным в X веке, Самватас, и встречающееся как имя в византийской надписи VI века, возводят либо к еврейскому, либо к хазарскому языку. Однако славянские топонимы «сувит», «собот» и пр. также очень распространены как обозначение «слияния», «соединения»[источник не указан 268 дней]. Сами же евреи, жители города, в переписке X века называли его Киевом.

При этом ряд учёных, в том числе профессор М. И. Артамонов, отмечают, что имена мифических братьев не носят никаких признаков славянской принадлежности. Так, гипотеза об иранских корнях имени легендарного Кыя (Кия из русской летописи) получила развитие в советской историографии у В. Н. Топорова. Также широко известна гипотеза американо-украинского востоковеда О. И. Прицака, который полагал, что возникновение Киева связано с хазарами и что Кий как личность тождественен гипотетическому хазарскому визирю Куйе. Гипотеза Прицака была подвергнута критике, как заведомо необоснованная[2][3].
//----
(вики)

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B9_%28%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C%29

Answer (score 1):

Рассматривая со стороны этногенеза (по версии Гумилёва) - славяне проживали на восточной стороне Эльбы, впоследствии перекочевали на территорию нынешней европейской части России, Украины и Белоруссии (Русы, кстати, тоже одно из племён). По беглому, непрофессиональному взгляду - имена больше всего "подошли бы" полякам либо украинцам.

Comment: Послушайте, название известно с IX века, реально существет с V века.
Какие украинцы? Какие поляки. Поля**не**. Славянское племя.

Comment: Хорошо, я даже выделю "... перекочевали на территорию НЫНЕШНЕЙ... ". Немцев, вы, видимо, тоже по старой привычке арийцами кличете.

Answer (score 1):

"Или же все они не были славянами, как всем известные Рюрик с братьями?" Даже современные немцы Вам расскажут о славянском происхождении Рюрика (Рарога), т.е. из балтийских славян. Герб нынешней Украины (падающий сокол - зап.слав. "рарог") - живое тому доказательство. Точно такой же герб у Ладоги, куда пришел Рюрик (Рарог) и у древней столицы ободритов - одноименного г.Рарога. В хронике города упоминается некий Рарог, который женился на дочери восточнославянского князя Гостомысла и ушел княжить в его земли. По времени события совпадают с "нашим" Рюриком. Это как же надо зомбироваться измышлениями немецких придворных  Екатерининских "историков", чтобы, не имея ни одного факта в пользу норманской ахинеи и имея документальные подтверждения славянского происхождения Рюрика, всё же упорно верить норманистам!

Comment: @Гусляр. Герб-трезубец, в виде "падающего сокола" известен ещё на печатях позднеантичного Крыма, лет поболее 300-т до появления Рюрика-"сокола", - точь в точь, такой же рисунок. Этот гербовый знак использовался и хазарами, что в наши дни даёт повод антиукраинским зубоскалам утверждать о хазарской тамге, как исходном символе киевского престольного княжения. Что означает этот знак, - трезубец, сокол или ещё что-то, - никто толком объяснить не может. Есть предположение, что это какой-то мистический символ.

Comment: Не знаю, при чем тут немцы, но варяжская версия происхождения Рюрика никем из серьезных авторов не оспаривалась.    
  
Каждый раз встает все тот же вопрос. А почему я должен верить Фоменке/Носовскому/Чудинову/Задорнову (кто там еще), а не Ключевскому/Карамзину/Лихачеву/Зализняку??? Для меня ответ очевиден.

Comment: Мне всегда казалось, что верить надо фактам, а не карамзиным, ключевским и даже, не побоюсь, зализнякам. Никто из вышеперечисленных не привел НИ ОДНОГО убедительного факта в пользу норманистики, один только упор на собственный вес в официальной науке. Но тут же не исторический форум, кто нам позволит развернуться? :)

Comment: >Мне всегда казалось, что верить надо фактам, что верить надо фактам, а не карамзиным, ключевским и даже, не побоюсь, зализнякам.
  
Фактов у вас нет. А у них они есть.

>Никто из вышеперечисленных не привел НИ ОДНОГО убедительного факта в пользу норманистики,  
  
Я не имел в виду конкретный разговор. Но вы себя опять выдали. Вы просто не читали оных авторов. Разве  Ключевский хоть слово сказал об истории дохристианкой Руси? Не назовете хоть одну его работу на эту тему? Он интересовался в основном историей, для него куда более близкой. Да и Зализняк - ученый совсем другого профиля.

Comment: behemothus, чудной Вы собеседник, сами с собой спорите. Откуда я знаю, что Вы каждый раз имеете в виду? ВЫ перечисляете имена, которым Вы слепо верите. Я отвечаю, что у них нет фактов в пользу норманистики. Вы говорите, что у них фактов и не может быть (!!!). Но при этом, в Вашем понимании, я "себя выдал" (???). Хотя выше Вы пишете, что "факты есть именно у них" (???). Вы, пожалуйста, наведите порядок в своих мыслях в соответствии с человеческой логикой, а то так ощущение, что общаешься с пораженным вирусом компьютером. В самом добром смысле этого слова. Ну, правда, без обид. :)

Comment: >сами с собой спорите  
  
Ну не с Вами же спорить? О чем? Вы пока не одной достойной обсуждения мысли не сформулировали.  

>Откуда я знаю, что Вы каждый раз имеете в виду?    
  
А читать мои слова не пробовали?
   
>у них нет фактов в пользу норманистики.    
  
А я вам отвечаю, что я и не утверждал, что есть. Я вообще не не собираюсь тут спорить о норманистике. И то, что не надо делать заявления подобное "нет ни одного факта", если вы не только не читали, но даже не представлеяте сферу научных интересов того, о ком говорите.   
  
Вообще разбирайтесь с Марком Изом. Он профессионал.

Comment: @behemothus, @Гусляр, я в норманские-антинорманские дебри не лезу, вопрос слишком политизирован. Как нам преподавал специалист по этому времени **скорей всего** Рюрик прибыл на Русь с территории современной Прибалтики и по всей видимости, был представителем финно-угорских народов.

Варяги (Рюрика?) стали катализатором усиления княжеской власти, и как следствие - окончательного становления государственности.

Comment: @Марк Из  Финно-угорских народов? Ага, есть подвижки от "норманов"! Это уже радует. А какие подтверждения в пользу финно-угров? Это для меня совсем новая история. Если из прибалтики, что действительно поддерживает уже большинство, то осталось набраться смелости и сделать ещё один честный шаг. Там как раз в ту пору балтийские славяне имели подавляющее распространение. Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: @behemothus "не надо делать заявления подобное "нет ни одного факта", если вы не только не читали, но даже не представлеяте сферу научных интересов того, о ком говорите." (Вы уже отвыкли выражаться на человеческом языке?) Да нафига мне Вам докладывать какую-то "сферу интересов" историков, которых Вы мне сами подкинули??? Ещё раз, сосредоточьтесь: я заявил, что фактов в пользу норманистики - нет. Если у Вас есть, предъявите. Не надо мне навязывать Вашу шоблу историков, кто что о чем писал. Конкретно по теме, хоть эти, хоть другие - что имеют в пользу норманитики? Отсчет пошёл...

Comment: @Гусляр, у Рюриковичей в генотипе геном характерный для шведов и балтских финно-угров, плюс различные письменные источники, с именами.

Comment: >...Рюрик прибыл на Русь с территории современной Прибалтики и по всей видимости, был представителем финно-угорских народов.//Варяги (Рюрика?) стали... 
  
Вы (ваш преподаватель) относите финно-унров к варягам?! Или полагаете что Рюрик был во главе чужеродного ему войска (отряда, каравана)?  
  
Остальное - да, не возражаю. Как одна из версий в рамках все той норманской теории. Пусть будет финн (хотя и вряд ли). Главное - что не славянин, не тюрок и не хазаренянин.   
  
А вопрос - да, излишне политизирован.

Comment: @behemothus, дело в том, что непонятно, что имелось в виду под словом "варяг". В византийских источниках так называют наёмников, коими могли быть не только скандинавы, но в последствии значение слова сдвигается к этносу. Ещё больше запутывает то, что слово "Русь" известно ещё до варягов, но жили русы на побережье Чёрного, а не Балтийского моря.

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу дать конкретный ответ на вопрос об именах первооснователей **Киева** и ограничусь только некоторыми деталями, с этим вопросом связанными. Город под названием  *КИЕВ***ец** (на Дунае) был известен по топонимам древнего Болгарского царства ещё поранее, чем появился нынешний Киев. (В Болгарском царстве был и город* Новеград*, тоже на Дунае.) То есть вполне возможно, что название* Киева *перенесено из Болгарии какими-то болгарскими переселенцами, и миф о трёх братьях и их сестре это перепев какого-то другого мифа - славянского(?), но не русского. /////// По поводу имен **Щек** и **Хорив** скажу следующее. **Щек** напоминает* чехов *(в чешском фольклоре братья-прародители - по имени* Чех *и* Лех */ляхи/), а **Хорив** напоминает* хорватов*. Однако есть и древнерусское слово **Щек** или **Щекот** - так называлась птичка **соловей**. В то же время существует и весьма распространённое еврейское имя* Харив*.

Comment: >То есть вполне возможно, что название Киева перенесено из Болгарии какими-то болгарскими переселенцами,    
   
Только если наоборот. Как из Киева мог получился "Киевец" (меленький киев) я представляю. А из Киевца - Киев? Это что-то ирреальное.

Comment: @behemothus. Я уважаю ваш патриотизм, но общая картина такова, что целый ряд болгарских реалий очутился в "Повести временных лет" в качестве реалий Киевской Руси. Перечислять и анализировать всё это не хватит места в комментах, не говоря уж о том, что наш Форум не есть исторический. И это не от ФиН, а от профессиональных, ещё советских, исследователей. И это по нынешнему Киев-ец суть маленький Киев, а по реалиям того времени -ец (в Болгарии) могло иметь иной смысловой оттенок. Вообще, думаю, что при том историческом материале, который мы имеем, ответит на вопрос @Тао невозможно.

Comment: При чем тут патриотизм?! O_o
Объясните по сути, как Киевец мог породить Киев.
Про реалии Повести временных лет - в другой раз.
В то что Нестор перепутал два города, простите, не поверю.  

Да, я отнюдь не думаю, что славянский суффикс "-ец" имел семантику "малый". Это суффикс принадлежности (сравните Ярополец, (Мало)ярославец, Торопец - и т.д.)
Но я вам показывал единственную возможную линию связи Киева и Киевца. Если вы её отвергаете, то и вообще всякое производство одного названия от другого следует исключить. Или давайте нефантастическую версию.

Comment: 
Про болгар - не надо. Это период славянской языковой общности, языки еще не разошлись так далеко.

Answer (score 1):

А я читала где-то, сайт был такой был, там ещё женщина автором была, не помню сейчас, что они вообще были евреями. Там и квартал, типа еврейский был в Киеве. И вроде из Хазар пришли. Ну что-то типа такого.

Comment: Ну, знаете)))

Это очень напоминает "Мне вчера анекдот рассказали. Начала я не слышал, середина неприличнная, а коней я забыл. Но ужасно смешно". Что за сайт, что за женщина?!  
В Киеве евреи жили  (где они только не жили), и версии о еврействе основателей Киева действительно есть. Но понимаете какая штука, поскольку реальность персонажей этой истории в общем-то отвергается, говорить об их национальности как-то не получается...

Comment: Простите, Вы как-то путано пишете: "а коней я забыл", "модно судить только по именам"... Кто-то меня упрекал в опечатках....

Comment: А, правда, кто отвергает реальность этих персонажей?

Comment: >кто отвергает реальность этих персонажей?

Реальность этих персонажей не столько отвергают, сколько сильно подвергают сомнению. Исторический факт должен быть подтверждён не менее чем двумя независимыми друг от друга источниками. Так как все эти персонажи дошли до нас лишь в мифическом сюжете летописца, жившего много после, описываемых им событий, то никаких оснований ему доверять нет.

Поляне по летописи платили дань хазарам (иудеи), но никаких оснований считать, что Киев основали не славяне, нет.

Comment: "Так как все эти персонажи дошли до нас лишь в мифическом сюжете летописца, жившего много после, описываемых им событий, то никаких оснований ему доверять нет." Получается, что нельзя доверять Ветхому Завету? Моисей написал через сколько веков после сотворения мира? Тогда и Ригведа и все остальные предания,и учение Будды было записано, что-то около 500 лет после. Ни чему доверять нельзя?

Comment: А все исторические события, которые мы признаем, были как минимум в двух источниках?

Comment: @Дилетантка, если исходить из религиозной точки зрения, то Моисей записал со слов непосредственного участника событий, а если с научной, то приписываемое Моисею Пятикнижие (Моисей никак не мог описать собственную смерть) - это сборник мифов и законов. Религия - это вопрос веры, а не науки.

>А все исторические события, которые мы признаем, были как минимум в двух источниках?

Да, иначе такой факт считается спорным. Из этого правила есть редкие исключения, вроде де-факто признанных существования Сократа или Иисуса, хотя споры по их реальному существованию по прежнему ведутся.

Comment: И исторические события Геродота, Флавия тоже все имеют другие источники подтверждения?

Comment: >И исторические события Геродота, Флавия тоже все имеют другие источники подтверждения?

Не все, хотя большинство подтверждены другими источниками или археологическими находками. В частности, описанный Геродотом захват власти Дарием I, подтверждается Бехистунской надписью, сделанной самим Дарием. Сравнение описаний греческого историка и текста на скале Бехистун, является классическим примером, установления исторического факта, путём сравнения двух источников, студенты-историки занимаются этим на 1 курсе обучения.

Comment: >Там и квартал, типа еврейский был в Киеве.

А в Иерусалиме, если не ошибаюсь, издавна есть армянский квартал. А в Нью-Йорке -- китайский. И что?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще интересно, есть три реки Лыбедь :  Рязань, Владимир, Киев.
Что еще более интересно, так это География.  Речка Лыбедь в Киеве 1850 года течет на самой окраине и ныне в бывшей заводской слободе Корчеватое впадает в Днепр. Ничем не знаменита, кроме как ссылками в исторических трудах. Теперь ее и речкой то не назовешь, коллектор. http://maps.vlasenko.net/historical/kiev/kiev-map-historical-1850.jpg
Речушка,  в овраге, далековато от  исторических мест , в стратегическом плане бесполезная.
http://maps.vlasenko.net/historical/kiev/kiev-map-historical-1700.jpg
раньше ее и речкой не называли.
А вот речки Лыбедь в Рязани и Владимире защищали крепости. Они почему то не в коллекторах. Полноводные как и были.
Известный  опять же только по историческим ссылкам остров на Днепре Лыбедь, попросту не существует. Но говорят он был, вопрос где?

ну, и до кучи.
Куявия (польск. Kujawy) — историческая область на севере Польши. Поморье. Нестора еще в помине не было.

Comment: А еще есть несколько Звенигородов, Переяславов...Ключевский, чтобы доказать, что был отлив населения в этом направлении прибегает к косвенным доказательствам: наиболее очевидным аргументом является топонимика, географические названия, топонимическое сходство северо-востока с южной Русью. Ключевский пишет: " Надо вслушаться в названия новых суздальских городов: Переяславль, Звенигород, Стародуб, Вышгород, Галич. Всё это южнорусские названия, которые мелькают чуть ли не на каждой странице летописи. Одних Звенигородов было несколько в земле Киевской и Галицкой.

Comment:  Имена киевских речек Лыбяди и Почайны встречаются в Рязани, в Нижнем Новгороде, во Владимире на Клязьме. Имя Киева не забыто в Суздальской земле, например село Киево в Московском уезде, Киевка — приток Оки в Калужском уезде, село Киевцы в Тульской Губернии. Три Переяславля известны древней Руси: южный, рязанский — это нынешняя Рязань( сюда перешли жители старой, домонгольской, сожжёной татарами Рязани), Переяславль залесский. Каждый из них стоит на реке Трубежь, также как и в Киевской Руси. Нетрудно догадаться, что это дело переселенцев.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не получать комментарии типа "киргизские пятнашки", хочу внести некоторые разъяснения. Человеческая речь (язык), как и речь маленьких детей, развивалась из коротких звуков, корней, понятий, которые были вначале многозначны. По мере совершенствования знаний, технологий и др. эти звукокорни сливались, образуя слова, однозначно определяющие предметы и явления. До разрушения Вавилонской башни (согласно Библии) был народ един и язык един. Затем народы разошлись, но эти звукокорни остались, хотя и несколько изменили своё звучание и значение в различных языках. Но в некоторых языках, которые менее всего были подвержены внешнему влиянию, они сохранились в большом количестве. Этими языками я считаю тюркские языки, в особенности киргизский (может быть благодаря словарю К.К. Юдахина). Хотя эти первичные звукокорни сохранились и в европейских языках. Например: английский - go - идти. Киргизский - ор - 1. яма, канава; 2. жать, косить; русский - орать - пахать; английский - ear - колос; немецкий - ohr - колос, похоже и в шведском, и в норвежском, и в других.
Теперь, удивительное созвучие: Кий Щек Хорив Лыбедь - на "тюркских": кый иш эк кор ива алы беде, если перевести, то получим: " подготавливая землю к посеву, вырубай и сей горячие угли ивы - возьмешь пшеницу". Отсюда: Киев (по-украински русскими буквами) Кыйив - вырубленные ивы. Может быть по этому многочисленная топонимика: Киев, Киевец и др. Тогда слова греческого автора: "... в Киеве крепость Самбатос ..." можно перевести так: " ... в расчищенном от ивы месте крепость са (твоя) ам (родительница) бат (авторитет, доброе имя) ос (рост, расти)". Ссылок никаких не привожу, хотя в вопросе о России один из комментаторов приводит текст Ключевского, который очень хорошо перекликается с моим комментарием.

Comment: С точки зрения этимологии - несерьезно. Приводите набор каких-то не связанных фактов (м без того самих по себе недостоверных) и без всяких дополнительных пояснений внушаете, что поняли этимологию "Киева".

Comment: А есть какие-нибудь сведения о контактах Киева с киргизами во времена его основания? Не помню историю, киргизы вообще с Енисея в горы-то тогда уже поднялись? Или еще там сидели, в болотах енисейских?